# How to show that $16-Y=(4-X)^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question: A rectangle of area $Y$ has a perimeter of $16$ and a side of length $X$. Show that $16-Y=(4-X)^2$

**My attempt:**

let $Z$ be the other side of rectangle,

\begin{align}
2X+2Z &= 16& (1)  \\
ZX &= Y  \\
Z &= Y/Z&(2)
\end{align}

sub $(2)$ into $(1)$:

\begin{align*}
2X^2+2Y &= 16X  \\
-Y &= X^2-8X  \\
-Y &= (X-4)^2 -16  \\
16-Y &= (X-4)^2
\end{align*}

**Why am I not getting $(4-X)$?**

Comment: The two expressions are equal. Observe that $a^2=(-a)^2$.

Comment: Sarim, you should learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in order to write formulas in an appropriate manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is fine. This is because $(X-4)^2=(4-X)^2$.

One way to see this is to go:
\begin{align}
(X-4)^2
&=(-1)^2(X-4)^2\\
&=((-1)\times(X-4))^2\\
&=(4-X)^2
\end{align}
as required.

Alternatively, we can break our brackets and compare the results:
$$
(X-4)^2=X^2-8X+(-4)^2=X^2-8X+16\\(4-X)^2=4^2-8X+(-X)^2=16-8X+X^2
$$
As $X^2-8X+16=16-8X+X^2$, we see that $(X-4)^2=(4-X)^2$ as required.